# What is Happening in This Java Code?

Tags: java, string, char, character, stringbuilder

If you don't mind, could you please explain something to me. i understand what this code does for the most part, and how it capitalizes the very first character in the String. What i don't understand is how is capitalizes words after a period, when i read the code it tells me that it "capitalizes" the position(pos) the period is in, not the character either directly after it or a whitespace then a character( "this.example" or "this. example"). Could someone please explain how this code is capitalizing the characters after the period. if need be, please use "today is. a good day" as what would be inputted as 'userInput'.

```
int pos = 0;
boolean capitalize = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(userInput);

while (pos < sb.length()) {

    if (sb.charAt(pos) == '.') {

        capitalize = true;
    } 
    else if (capitalize && !Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(pos))) {

        sb.setCharAt(pos, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(pos)));

        capitalize = false;
    }
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: as an aside, this code is more suited with a `for` loop than with a `while` loop.

Comment: Very possible that we are doing this person's coding test for him, either as part of an assignment or part of an interview process.

Comment: this is involved in no sort or test or assignment, i am simply trying to better understand java, and better my knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a crude sort of state machine. Only the `if` or the `else if` block (or neither) is going to be executed on each iteration of the loop. If the current character is a `.`, then the `capitalize` flag is set to `true` and nothing else happens on that iteration. This flag is telling your code to capitalize the next non-space character it sees.

The loop then takes you to the next character, where it checks to see if the `capitalize` flag is `true` *and* the character is not whitespace. If that's the case, the character is capitalized and the flag is reset to `false`. If it is a space character, then nothing happens (the `capitalize` flag stays `true` for the next iteration).

Comment: Thank you very much! i can't tell you how much time i spent looking at and reading out loud the process in which i thought the code would execute to try and understand it. you have helped me out tremendously!

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the method `setCharAt()` which takes two parameters as mentioned below and used to set the specified character at the specified index:-

`public void setCharAt(int index, char ch)`, So here you are passing ***"pos"*** as a ***"index"*** of character and ***"`Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(pos))`"*** as character